# Convert a CSV file with objects to JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson, jackson-databind

I have to convert JSON files into CSV and vice-versa, i use the Jackson library.

Going from JSON to CSV works well, for every type of data, including nested objects, but the counter way is much more harder, as the CSVMapper parse the CSV in a map, thus a couple .

Even if my actual works for simple CSV files, it doesn't for CSV that should produce JSON objects like this

#### JSON File

```
[
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters":
            {
                "batter":
                    [
                        { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                        { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                        { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                    ]
            },
        "topping":
            [
                { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
            ]
    },
]
```

#### CSV file after the conversion

```
batters.batter[1].id;batters.batter[1].type;batters.batter[2].id;batters.batter[2].type;batters.batter[3].id;batters.batter[3].type;batters.batter[4].id;batters.batter[4].type;id;name;ppu;topping[1].id;topping[1].type;topping[2].id;topping[2].type;topping[3].id;topping[3].type;topping[4].id;topping[4].type;topping[5].id;topping[5].type;topping[6].id;topping[6].type;topping[7].id;topping[7].type;type

1001;Regular;1002;Chocolate;1003;Blueberry;1004;Devil's Food;0001;Cake;0.55;5001;None;5002;Glazed;5005;Sugar;5007;Powdered Sugar;5006;Chocolate with Sprinkles;5003;Chocolate;5004;Maple;donut
```

### CSV to JSON converter

```
File csvFile = new File(CSV_File) ;
// Get the name of the file, for the new one in JSON
// String file_name = csvFile.getName().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");;

CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();

mapper.disable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY);

CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader(); // use first row as header; otherwise defaults are fine
MappingIterator<Map<String,String>> it = mapper.readerFor(Map.class)
   .with(schema)
   .readValues(csvFile);

// We extract a list from the mapping Iterator
List<Map<String, String>> readObjectsFromCsv = it.readAll() ;
// Clean the list
readObjectsFromCsv = cleanCSV(readObjectsFromCsv) ;

// Build the JSON file
try {

    ObjectMapper mapperObject = new ObjectMapper() ;

    // Write JSON formated data to output.json file
    mapperObject.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(new File(JSON_File),readObjectsFromCsv);


    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

#### The output of this code

```
[ {
 "batters.batter[1].id" : "1001",
 "batters.batter[1].type" : "Regular",
 "batters.batter[2].id" : "1002",
 "batters.batter[2].type" : "Chocolate",
 "batters.batter[3].id" : "1003",
 "batters.batter[3].type" : "Blueberry",
 "batters.batter[4].id" : "1004",
 "batters.batter[4].type" : "Devil's Food",
 "id" : "0001",
 "name" : "Cake",
 "ppu" : "0.55",
 "topping[1].id" : "5001",
 "topping[1].type" : "None",
 "topping[2].id" : "5002",
 "topping[2].type" : "Glazed",
 "topping[3].id" : "5005",
 "topping[3].type" : "Sugar",
 "topping[4].id" : "5007",
 "topping[4].type" : "Powdered Sugar",
 "topping[5].id" : "5006",
 "topping[5].type" : "Chocolate with Sprinkles",
 "topping[6].id" : "5003",
 "topping[6].type" : "Chocolate",
 "topping[7].id" : "5004",
 "topping[7].type" : "Maple",
 "type" : "donut"
} ]
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem in your CSV->JSON converter. Can you post code of the CSV->JSON converter?

Comment: I posted it, check the CSV to JSON code, i also posted its output

Answer (score 0):

Just one more step can get the final result. That is to unflatten your JSON output.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[ {" +
    " \"batters.batter[1].id\" : \"1001\"," +
    " \"batters.batter[1].type\" : \"Regular\"," +
    " \"batters.batter[2].id\" : \"1002\"," +
    " \"batters.batter[2].type\" : \"Chocolate\"," +
    " \"batters.batter[3].id\" : \"1003\"," +
    " \"batters.batter[3].type\" : \"Blueberry\"," +
    " \"batters.batter[4].id\" : \"1004\"," +
    " \"batters.batter[4].type\" : \"Devil's Food\"," +
    " \"id\" : \"0001\"," +
    " \"name\" : \"Cake\"," +
    " \"ppu\" : \"0.55\"," +
    " \"topping[1].id\" : \"5001\"," +
    " \"topping[1].type\" : \"None\"," +
    " \"topping[2].id\" : \"5002\"," +
    " \"topping[2].type\" : \"Glazed\"," +
    " \"topping[3].id\" : \"5005\"," +
    " \"topping[3].type\" : \"Sugar\"," +
    " \"topping[4].id\" : \"5007\"," +
    " \"topping[4].type\" : \"Powdered Sugar\"," +
    " \"topping[5].id\" : \"5006\"," +
    " \"topping[5].type\" : \"Chocolate with Sprinkles\"," +
    " \"topping[6].id\" : \"5003\"," +
    " \"topping[6].type\" : \"Chocolate\"," +
    " \"topping[7].id\" : \"5004\"," +
    " \"topping[7].type\" : \"Maple\"," +
    " \"type\" : \"donut\"" +
    "} ]");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("[]@.unflatten('.[]')");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
[ {
  "batters" : {
    "batter" : [ {
      "id" : "1001",
      "type" : "Regular"
    }, {
      "id" : "1002",
      "type" : "Chocolate"
    }, {
      "id" : "1003",
      "type" : "Blueberry"
    }, {
      "id" : "1004",
      "type" : "Devil's Food"
    } ]
  },
  "id" : "0001",
  "name" : "Cake",
  "ppu" : "0.55",
  "topping" : [ {
    "id" : "5001",
    "type" : "None"
  }, {
    "id" : "5002",
    "type" : "Glazed"
  }, {
    "id" : "5005",
    "type" : "Sugar"
  }, {
    "id" : "5007",
    "type" : "Powdered Sugar"
  }, {
    "id" : "5006",
    "type" : "Chocolate with Sprinkles"
  }, {
    "id" : "5003",
    "type" : "Chocolate"
  }, {
    "id" : "5004",
    "type" : "Maple"
  } ],
  "type" : "donut"
} ]
```